# Open window when wake up from hibernation

Tags: windows, wakeup

I dont know if this is possible but ill try to explain and see if any of you know something tyhat can help me with this.

I have a pc with a firefox page open, i need that when the pc wake up from hibernation it open that page in firefox.
I need this to be automated so no one forget to check that page everyday.

is that possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add applications to Startup by going to Start Menu > Startup folder > Drag Firefox shortcut icon to Startup folder. This will start the program whenever windows starts up. Firefox will open on startup to whatever page you have saved as your startup page.

Another option instead of booting up the webpage whenever the computer wakes up, is to use an app like [this one](http://www.e-motional.com/autowebview.htm) that displays a webpage as a screen saver.

Comment: I was also thinking about that. Was only thinking about it the "startup" tasks also fire when resuming from hibernation? Or is that only on login?

Comment: I already have it on startup the problem is that they dont shutdown, they put the computers to sleep

Comment: @RicardoSimoes see my edit, instead of showing on startup you can have it show as a screensaver, then they'll see every time they come back to their computer.

Comment: the screensaver option dont strike me as very secure they would probably touch the mouse before even looking at the screen

Comment: @RicardoSimoes - But it would at least remind them that they need to check the page if they haven't already.